# Autofac with .NET 6 console app and ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, .net-6.0

I am trying to use `ServiceCollection` with Autofac populating the `ServiceCollection` in a Console App. I read through [the documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html?highlight=AddAutofac#asp-net-core-1-1-2-2) but there is no guide for my specific scenario.

The issue I am facing is that built ServiceCollection does not find the implementation when I ask with interface type. I think AutoFac is not populating the `ServieCollection`.

`Program.cs`

```
using System.Reflection;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Core.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole())
    .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(cfg => cfg.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information)
    .AddAutofac(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Core")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
    })
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var markDownParser = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMarkDownParser>();
```

`MarkDownParser.cs`

```
namespace Core;

public class MarkDownParser : IMarkDownParser
{
    private readonly ILogger<MarkDownParser> _logger;

    public MarkDownParser(ILogger<MarkDownParser> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

`IMarkDownParser.cs`

```
namespace Core.Interfaces;

public interface IMarkDownParser
{
    object Parse(string text);
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Core.Interfaces.IMarkDownParser' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /home/amir/RiderProjects/git-blog/ConsoleApp/Program.cs:line 20
```

Comment: What's the namespace from `IMarkDownParser` and `MarkDownParser`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is on [`AddAutofac`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html?highlight=AddAutofac#asp-net-core-1-1-2-2) extension method only supports during **ASP.NET Core 1.1 - 2.2**.

> This is not for ASP.NET Core 3+ or the .NET Core 3+ generic hosting support - ASP.NET Core 3 has deprecated the ability to return a service provider from ConfigureServices.

if we want to use autofac to be the DI Container, there is an example to talk about [netcore quick-start](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html#quick-start)

Once you've registered everything in the ServiceCollection and call `Populate` to bring those registrations into Autofac by `ContainerBuilder`

Final, Creating a new `AutofacServiceProvider` makes the DI container and we can use that.

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole())
    .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(cfg => cfg.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information);

var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.Populate(serviceCollection);
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Core")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
var container = containerBuilder.Build();

var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
var markDownParser = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMarkDownParser>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says that only use `AddAutofac` 
`ONLY FOR PRE-ASP.NET 3.0 HOSTING. THIS WON'T WORK FOR ASP.NET CORE 3.0+ OR GENERIC HOSTING.`
Since `.net 6` has been tagged. I'm thinking the framework is part of the issue.
Here is my implementation as well as some documentation to help.
https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

// Main

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Reflection;

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Core")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
})
.Build();

var markDownParser = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMarkDownParser>();
Console.WriteLine(markDownParser);
```

// Core Assembly

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Core
{
    public interface IMarkDownParser
    {
        object Parse(string text);
    }

    public class MarkDownParser : IMarkDownParser
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MarkDownParser> _logger;

        public MarkDownParser(ILogger<MarkDownParser> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public object Parse(string text)
        {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about unit tests in this case? IMO there is no host in this use case.